# Display Query from SQLite3 Database into Bootstrap table

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, bootstrap-table

i want to display my query from SQLite3 into Bootstrap Table. but it seems doesnt work and wont display the table.
herewith my code

#### views.py

```
@main.route('/currentlist', methods=["GET"])
def current():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        Connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Backup_old\\Task\\e_ticket\\my_app\\db\\customer.db')
        cursor = Connection.cursor()
        query2 = "SELECT * from customer"
        cursor.execute(query2)
        test = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('overview.html', testform = test)
```

#### HTML

```
<div class= "content">

      <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Date
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">time
            <th class="th-sm">customer
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">pic
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">category
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">description
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>9 December 2021</td>
            <td>15:30:00</td>
            <td>AB Corp.</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>network</td>
            <td>network is down</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9 December 2021</td>
            <td>17:30:00</td>
            <td>AB Corp.</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td>computer</td>
            <td>computer is broken</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10 December 2021</td>
            <td>05:32:00</td>
            <td>CD Corp.</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Server</td>
            <td>server is down</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12 December 2021</td>
            <td>10:30:00</td>
            <td>AB Corp.</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>printer</td>
            <td>printer is down</td>
          </tr>


        </tbody>
        
      </table>
    



    </div>
```

it should be like this but with the data from DB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKVDR.png)

i've read many similiar question like this, but most of them use SQLAlchemy.

**Any help greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop and template variables with the data.

```
<tbody>
  {% for row in testform %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```